# Swift type does not conform to protocol error at generic constraint but not at class itself

Tags: swift

I'm having some troubles figuring this whole thing out here.
Starting from code:

Entity:

```
protocol EntityProtocol : class {
    var id: String { get set }
    var version: String { get }
    var deleted: Bool { get set }
    var uid: String { get set }
    func Validate() -> [String: String]
}
extension EntityProtocol {
    var version: String {
        get { return "v0.0" }
        set { }
    }
    func Validate() -> [String: String]{
        //some default checking for default fields
    }
}
typealias Entity = EntityProtocol & Codable
```

Product:

```
class Product: Entity {
    var id: String = ""
    var deleted: Bool
    var uid: String = ""

    func Validate() -> [String : String] {
      //implementation
    }
}
```

Up until now, no errors when compiling... Then I have `class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity: Entity` a base class which implements the actual repository functionality...

Now when I do `class ProductRepo<Product> : Repository<Product>` it shows an error here saying `Type 'Product' does not conform to protocol 'EntityProtocol'` However, still no error in the Product class itself.

P.S: I've tried to add the `version` field to product, still same error.
The reason I'm using protocol not class with inheritance is that Codable can not be inherited and will have to write init and serialize myself.

Anyone can tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? I'm confused that if Product does not conform to protocol, then why compiler does not complain in the Product class itself?

Comment: The compiler can add protocol stubs for you. This discovers the mistake at once.

Comment: I think simple  `class ProductRepo: Repository<Product>` should suffice, why is child class inheriting from parent `Repository` class also needs to specify a generic type? as you did `class ProductRepo<Product>: Repository<Product>` ??? Not sure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Product might be subclassed later for added functionality so I was trying to leave some space for it.

Comment: hmmmm, gotcha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProductRepo` declaration is missing a type constraint on `Product`. You need to add the `Entity` constraint to it to make it conform to `Repository`.

```
class ProductRepo<Product: Entity> : Repository<Product> {
    
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but there's no need for having `Entity` as a type alias, you can simply make `EntityProtocol` conform to `Codable`. Also, for the `version` default implementation, there's no need for adding an empty setter, since the protocol only requires a getter.

```
protocol Entity: class, Codable {
    var id: String { get set }
    var version: String { get }
    var deleted: Bool { get set }
    var uid: String { get set }
    func validate() -> [String: String]
}

extension Entity {
    var version: String {
        "v0.0"
    }
    
    func validate() -> [String: String]{
        [:]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U tried adding version field to product, but u should also make **version {get set}** in EntityProtocol protocol then it will work

```
protocol EntityProtocol : class {
    var id: String { get set }
    var version: String { get }
    var deleted: Bool { get set }
    var uid: String { get set }
    func Validate() -> [String: String]
}
```

Comment: Added set to version in EntityProtocol, added version field to Product. Still having same compile error.